# As an international student applying for internships abroad, how can I improve my chances at getting an interview?

Tags: software-industry, internship, united-states, international

As an international student applying for internships abroad, how can I improve my chances at getting an interview?

Comment: The resume is formatted very good for reading by human, but for automated systems it can be too fancy. Maybe you should not upload it as pdf. Use Word document, standard fonts, one column for the information, bullets instead of tables

Comment: you are being victim of the most stupid invention of the world : a robot who evaluate programmer skills by parsing their resume. Make everything to have a real human you can send your resume to.

Comment: This question can only answered by the companies (or automated systems) that are rejecting you and the Workplace isn't a resume review service. Most likely you should be applying to internship offers that allow international candidates rather than submitting a resume out of the blue. There are also several problems with your resume, have a look on this site or on the web for do's and don'ts. Bad Things that I immediately notice: overdesigned, too long, includes a picture (virtually always an automatic rejection in the US), listing an unexceptional percentage, no graduation date, ...

Comment: @yask, I don't mean to be harsh, I just don't want you to set yourself up for disappointment. Don't expect that once you follow the advice from the answers and fix your resume, getting an internship will become easy. Not that you shoud give up, I encourage you to keep searching. Just don't bet your life on this, if you get a decent offer at a local company, go for it.

Comment: Are you eligible to work as a technical intern in a California company at all? From the CV it seems that you are not a citizen or resident of USA, it would be illegal to do this internship on a tourist visa, and the major work-visa types including H1B would not be available for internship positions.  It doesn't make sense to interview or evaluate you if they can't hire you anyway.

Comment: Also note that internship applications from India have a particularly loaded history, as [this Academia thread explains](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/what-is-behind-the-indian-undergrad-research-experience-spam/41693#41693) (internships can be at universities or in industry). This coupled with the legal hassle and the fact that there are usually plenty of candidates for internships means that you will have a very low chance of getting such an internship unless you have personal contacts.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How can a recent graduate get an international internship?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2606/2322). Also my answer to [Applying for an American internship as a foreign student living in Germany](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/8934/2322) is very applicable here, too. Keep in mind popular companies probably get hundreds if not thousands of applications from international students/graduates.

Comment: All of the companies you mention are among the largest, most popular, and most elite companies in the software industry. They probably get millions of internship applications every year, and can't possibly interview everyone. Unless you are in the top tier of a very good university, I would not be surprised at all to get cut so early.

Comment: You should probably reword your question to something like, "As an student seeking an internship, I keep applying to companies [20+] and not even getting an interview. What can I do to improve my odds of getting an interview and a job?"

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Maybe not the best way to judge candidates, but if you rank me by no. of stars on Github projects, this is how I stand. http://app.trendingdevs.com/developers/yask123 
In India, people don't care much about your projects/opensource contributions. They mostly hire by competitive programming competitions. I was applying to  these companies because I thought, they might consider self taken projects.. and value open source contributions. Apparently they don't :(

Comment: @vladiz I am not sure I would recommend the two column format even for human reading. I had to scroll backwards and forwards to read the sections. It would have been more convenient in a simpler one column format.

Comment: Your resume looks pretty but lacks content. That includes soft skills. I would make it more traditional and remove the picture

Comment: @yask If they cannot legally employ you, there is no reason for them to look at your projects, and interviewing you would be a waste of time. The first step is to identify companies that can and do offer internships to students with your nationality and immigration status.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I applied at those places where they had option to select "Require Visa Sponsorship"

Comment: @yask Just be careful to pick ones that are doing visa sponsorship for interns, not just for long term employees.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Only the companies you applied to could tell you why you were not selected to go further in the process.

However, to improve your **odds of being selected** there are a few things you can do:

1. Your resume is too long and not standard. As a student you should have a single page resume. It should focus on important skills, accomplishments and facts about you. Most companies/recruiters won't look past the first page anyway. Resume tips:

Tip #1: Do not put a picture of yourself on a resume unless your looks matter to getting the job.

Tip #2: Do not self-assess your skills. Communicate your skills by listing them and mentioning them when describing projects/experience. Beyond that an interview will allow the company to assess the skills. What if you discovered that you rated yourself worse than they would have?

Tip #3: Black and white. An "attention grabbing resume" can land you a job, but the *odds are you will look too risky* or *never even be seen* under normal circumstances. Any kind of automation may fail trying to decipher your creativity - and why would anyone go through the list of failed resumes looking for a "diamond in the rough" when they have a nice stack of resumes that didn't fail? And why try to figure out your resume when it's easy to read someone else's standard resume?

Tip #4: When listing experience, say what you did (an action) and the result (accomplishment). When you are on the job, your actions and results are what matter, so demonstrate your awareness on your resume.

Tip #5: Adapt your resume for the particular job for which you are applying. A generic resume is usually a weak resume. Each job and company is different. You should modify your resume to emphasize the skills that are appropriate for the particular job you are seeking, and remove everything else until it's 1 page.

There are lots of resources on how to write resumes. I'm not sure what resource you used to produce your resume, but I don't think the format and style you used are commonly accepted as successful.

2. If you only apply to companies with a lot of competition then your odds of success are low in general. If these companies get 100 resumes for each position, then expect to send out 100 resumes at least. Regardless of whether you are a top candidate, expect that all applicants are as equally qualified as you. The website you reference doesn't indicate the supply/demand for the internships, but given the area nearly all of them are going to have a lot of candidates.
3. As a student from India, if you want to work in the US, the odds are slim with most companies. Not that they don't want to recruit from abroad or that they don't, but it's much easier and less risky to select candidates that already are in the country in which they need employees, or to select experienced candidates.

Comment: +1 for the single page. I ended up with 2 resumes : One 1-pager to get attention, and one full with all details. That is after years of experience & consulting. The single page as a first contact still is very efficient(but always have the "true" one in your bag).

Comment: Regarding the tips, anyone whose only listed development experience is < 1 year and puts "advanced" in multiple programming technologies is... probably going to be less than convincing and immediately cause concern for someone reviewing the resume.

Comment: @enderland  Agreed, its relative, I'll get rid of those. But..I have been doing java since 9th grade from my school days, and had semester courses on "Advanced Java, C++ and C" in college. 
That's all I wanted to convey. 
Also, i may not have internship experience to show that, but I have been doing multiple self taken projects: http://iyask.me/#projects , and contributing to open source softwares.

Comment: @yask your resume doesn't though, it looks like you started programming in 2015.

Comment: @enderland I do have links to my portfolio page http://iyask.me and github profile in my resume though.
https://github.com/yask123

Comment: @enderland One of my self taken  trended at #1 spot on HackerNews for more than a day and recieved over 900 stars on Github.
https://github.com/yask123/Instant-Music-Downloader

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are great general advise, but point 3 is really why the OP is being rejected out of hand.

Comment: @yask A 143 line python method full of fragile hacks is not a beautiful thing.

Comment: @Eric It's not wise to judge a program by no. of lines, also it contains 286 lines (https://github.com/yask123/Instant-Music-Downloader/blob/master/instantmusic-0.1/bin/instantmusic) .

>fragile hacks is not a beautiful thing : Thanks for criticism, I'll continue to improve myself... but I am still proud of my projects (Given the background I come from, and that I am 3rd year undergrad and 20yrs old). I know this may not be as impressive as  Linus torvald's kernel when he was 22 years old.. or one of your projects.., but don't you think I deserve a chance to be interviewed?

Comment: @Eric , regardless of the no. of lines of projects, I still think its cool to have a self taken project trended at #1 on HN and received tons of Pull Requests. It felt great that so many people were/ are using it.

Comment: @Eric , I also built http://www.jeequery.com , which has more number of lines of code. It is a full fledged Django QnA application (Similar to StackOverflow) , but exclusively for students preparing for IIT engineering entrance exams.
I also built http://www.stalky.in which trended on Reddit.
I also improved UI/UX of (As my GSoC project) for Moin Moin wiki which is used by  Ubuntu, Apache, Debian, FreeBSD.

Comment: @yask I think you're missing Eric's point, which is you have a couple methods that are just too long and unwieldy, not that your code base is not large enough.  It looks like you did some good work though; I'm glad to see your confidence is not shattered :)  I would have to point out the interesting contrast between this discussion and your resume though.  How can your resume clearly convey the work you've done without the reader having to follow your links?  You realize they have less than 15 seconds to decide whether to flush your resume down the toilet.  They are not gonna check your links.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Aha!. yep! I did miss Eric's point. Sorry about that.  I'll try to improve my resume keeping your points in mind. Also, since most of you guys are from SDE field (I got that by looking at your profiles).. can you share an example resume (In which a candidate tried to get recruiter's attention to their projects).

Comment: I am currently rebuilding my resume, I hope this one should pass the bots ? http://iyask.me/resume/

Comment: @yask Your skills should not be "Likes", just skills.  Participating in GSOC makes you a "GSOC participant" not a "contract developer".  Not everyone understands what a B.Tech in IT in India means.  You should elaborate on the content of what you are learning.  Most student resume's I see have some description of coursework.  Your projects show you have a lot of enthusiasm, but they also show you to be an enthusiastic amateur.  They should definitely be mentioned, but they should be less prominently featured.  Take care not to oversell yourself as that will also land your resume in the trash.

Answer (score 14):

At a quick look, I saw two issues.

One, that you mention, is work authorization. You are applying for jobs in California giving a non-US location with no indication that you are authorized to work in the US. That means additional work for HR compared to other applicants. Why California, rather than India, for an internship? Have you tried e.g. through your school, to identify companies that do hire interns internationally?

Another issue is resume format - this may affect applications even in India. I don't know how smart the automated resume processing programs are now, but will they be able to easily determine your skills etc? It may be better to try a simpler, more linear, more text-orientated format.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like you have a degree. There will be many candidates applying for these high profile .coms that do have one so you will be immediately ruled out if that is not immediately clear. Also are the percentages grades or % complete?

The best way to get a job is through networking to make industry contacts and get a recommendation, try and speak to people through conferences, webinars, programs like summer of code. Also you may need to target less well known companies where the competition isn't so large.

Answer (score 5):

There is a single reason:

**You weren't able to make it through their automated gauging system**. The interviews, etc would start after that.

So, there is a very high probability that the company/recruiter has not even seen your resume.

Comment: The reason why I couldn't make it through their `automated gauging system` ?

Comment: There'd be several custom-defined parameters by the companies.  For example, your CGPA, intern exp. (yes/no), etc.   [This](http://lifehacker.com/5866630/how-can-i-make-sure-my-resume-gets-past-resume-robots-and-into-a-humans-hand) might be helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can't see what the exactly the process is for applying through this website without registering, which I won't do. So I can't say if they ask for a cover letter. Often the CV has to be accompanied by a cover letter explaining why you're interested in working the job in question for this company. If the cover letter is too generic, or has obvious grammatical or spelling errors, the CV goes directly into the trash.

The CV looks pretty, but for a student I would expect a much more complete entry in "education", to get an idea of how old you are and if you skipped some years. There should be a standard form of the title you earn on graduation, and the expected date of graduation. "Education" should not be split into 2 parts on 2 pages.  Additionally, the dates are some of the most important information, but they are somewhat hard to find - To make them easier to find for human and other readers, consider putting them on the same line as the event they belong to.

Being a foreign student from the other side of the world with presumably unknown work status also puts you at a severe disadvantage, because if you were to make it to later rounds, flying you in for a face to face interview is going to be expensive. And you also need a permit, so you will be held to higher standards. To make things worse, **Indian CVs are very well known to often be hugely exaggerated**, so even if yours is not, you will suffer by the actions of your peers.

As always, the best chance to land a hard to get job is through personal contacts, not some website. The world is smaller than you think. Maybe a professor at your university knows a guy who knows a guy? Or one of the code reviewers of the open source projects you worked on is a PM at Mozilla?